# Changing SATA HDD speed with jumper

Tags: hard-drive, sata, jumper

I'm having some problems using a new Samsung SATA 2 500gb HD with an Asus K8V-X motherboard. [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/298742/trouble-with-new-hard-drive-on-old-computer-and-bios-update), also made by me, is related.

Found [this forum post](http://www.motherboardpoint.com/asus-k8v-x-problem-detecting-sata-drives-t152285.html) on google where someone said that the motherboard might not have support for SATA 2 HDDs, even thought SATA is supposed to be backward compatible. I'd have to limit my new HDD speed to SATA 1 and maybe my motherboard would recognize it. The problem is I don't know how to set it to SATA 1. I found manuals [here](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/hdd/productmodel.do?group=72&type=94&subtype=98&subSubType=115&model_cd=469) but they do not mention anything about limiting SATA HDD speed by placing jumpers. They only describe how to set PATA drives to master, slave or cable select. How can I set my SATA 2 HDD to SATA 1 with jumpers?

Comment: If your SATA 2 HD won't work on your SATA 1 motherboard without jumper or other configuration settings, then one or the other of them is "broken as shipped." Possibly both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through it, it might solve you problem.

http://www.samsung.com/global/business/hdd/faqView.do?b2b_bbs_msg_id=121

Comment: Nice, this is exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately my motherboard still doesn't recognize it. Thanks anyways!